# Web site from PC to mobile and content size problems

Tags: css, web, smartphone

I have a web application for PC screen browsers (@media screen{}) and I want to make it friendly for smartphone screens.

Unfortunately my 12pt fonts and my 128x128 pictures appear very small in my smartphone with a 1280x800 resolution (Samsung-Google Nexus).

Before make additions to CSS for a smartphone like mine, what I must have in mind to create a web application for a variety of smartphone screen resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add this in css :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=false;">
```

from : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

History about viewport, i'm not sure....

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to create a responsive website- Responsive, Designed for mobile, and Mobile first. However, nowadays, we consider more about `Mobile First!`. So, there are many websites teaching you how to create a responsive websites and mobile first approach for example:

1. [Firstwebdesigner](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-a-responsive-website-video-tutorial/)
2. [WebdesignTuts](http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-responsive-mobile-first-navigation--webdesign-6074)

The first thing to think of when building a responsive site is simplicity. Web designers love to show off that they can design the hell out of a website. They fall in love with their code and all the cool things that it can do.

**10 Basic tips about responsive design**

> 1. Keep your layout simple
> 2. Use media queries
> 3. Define the break points
> 4. Make your layout flexible
> 5. Make your picture behave
> 6. Don't foget make and min
> 7. Make most things relative
> 8. When mobile linearize
> 9. Skip the none essential content
> 10. Check your meta viewport

You can see more information on [Dan Rowinski's article](http://readwrite.com/2013/04/16/10-developer-tips-to-build-a-responsive-website-infographic#awesm=~oiGdcWqHJGnhs8). This is a great article to answer your question,  what you must think before creating a responsive web application.